# Multiplying all values in Pandas Dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is basically the dataframe:

```
      col1    col2    col3    label
row1   1       0       1        1
row2   0       0       0        1
row3   1       1       1        0
row4   1       2       1        0
```

I basically need it to go over each row, and if label = 0, multiply all the values in the row by -1.

I've tried many different approaches, including:

```
df.ix[3] = df.ix[3].multiply(-1)
```

Which returns:

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I've also tried dropping the row and replacing, which doesn't work because the indexes change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can run an `apply` for row-wise operations:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: row*-1 if row['label'] == 0 else row, axis=1)

print(df)    
#       col1  col2  col3  label
# row1     1     0     1      1
# row2     0     0     0      1
# row3    -1    -1    -1      0
# row4    -1    -2    -1      0
```

Comment: Hi! This worked very fast, but it multiplied everything by -1. Not sure what to change to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [156]: df.loc[df.label==0, df.columns.drop('label')] = \
              df.loc[df.label==0, df.columns.drop('label')].mul(-1)

In [157]: df
Out[157]:
      col1  col2  col3  label
row1     1     0     1      1
row2     0     0     0      1
row3    -1    -1    -1      0
row4    -1    -2    -1      0
```

or bit shorter version:

```
In [160]: df.loc[df.label==0, df.columns.drop('label')] *= -1

In [161]: df
Out[161]:
      col1  col2  col3  label
row1     1     0     1      1
row2     0     0     0      1
row3    -1    -1    -1      0
row4    -1    -2    -1      0
```

Comment: Hey there! I got the same "SettingWithCopyWarning". As in the case of my other reply, the script doesn't error out, it's just very slow. It takes a while with around 30 rows, and the final dataset has about 3k. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

One approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `masking`, basically using the fact that multiplying `0` by `-1` won't change `0`, so we can multiply the entire rows by `-1` that have the corresponding `label` values as `0s` -

```
df[(df.label==0)] *= -1
```

Sample run -

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
      col1  col2  col3  col4  label
row1     1     0     1     3      1
row2     0     0     0     2      1
row3     1     1     1     5      0
row4     1     2     1     7      0

In [71]: df[(df.label==0)] *= -1

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
      col1  col2  col3  col4  label
row1     1     0     1     3      1
row2     0     0     0     2      1
row3    -1    -1    -1    -5      0
row4    -1    -2    -1    -7      0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, using this I got the same SettingWithCopyWarning. The script doesn't necessarily stop, but it just stays there running. Not sure I made it clear enough, but I need thsi new dataframe to be stored somewhere, either replacing or as a new df. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @AMC Try : `df_out = df.mul(2*(df.label!=0)-1, axis=0)`? That `df_out` would be the new/output dataframe.

Comment: That multiplied everything by -1, for some reason. Even changing to df.label == 0.

Comment: @AMC Maybe you have strings in there. So, try `df.mul(2*(df.label.values.astype(int)!=0)-1,axis=0)`.